# iOS neither init or initWithCoder are been called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I add a `tableView` to my `viewController` and I need to initialize some properties. But neither `-(id)init`  or `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder` are been called.

my header file:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

Any of you knows why or how can either init methods get call?

I really appreciate your help

Comment: is `initWithNibName:bundle:` being called?

Comment: How are you initializing an instance of myViewController?

Comment: its been initialize in the AppDelegate

Comment: He means to show the code you have in AppDelegate that initialises the ViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [UIViewController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that `initWithNibName:bundle:` is the designated initializer. That's the one you should override if you're doing stuff during initialization.

**Update:** Right, as pointed out by Simon, you would override `initWithCoder:` if you're using a storyboard (though I assume OP is not, as he said `initWithCoder:` is not getting called).

Comment: Not if you are instantiating it from a storyboard!  In that case, the initializer that gets called is `-initWithCoder:`